# how do we implode or explode an array in angular 5

Tags: arrays, angular, angular5

I have used a `mat-select` element on my project :

```
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" formControlName="toppings" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"> 
          {{topping}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

the data of topping list is:

```
  toppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
```

so now whenever I select multiple values from the sidebar the value is returned in an array format. I had used
 `const stringOfColours = form.toppings.join(', ');`
to convert the array into string and insert it into database. But now how can I pre-select all the previous selected values by fetching the same data from the database in the edit page of the same. (if there are other way of inserting the array into a single cell of database please suggest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use split function and assign it in FormControl element in your Form in ngOnInit method:

```
ngOnInit(){
    selectedToppingListFromDatabase = ['Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Tomato'];
    this.your_form.controls.toppings.setValue(selectedToppingList.split(', '));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can `split` the string to array and set the value using `setValue`

```
let toppingArr = yourString.split(',');
this.yourFormGroup.setValue({
  toppings: toppingArr,  
});
```

Comment: Should use the `toppingArr` directly: `this.yourFormGroup.setValue(toppingArr);`